# При попытке выполнить POST запрос к ASP core API, используя JS происходит зависание

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

Есть ASP core API с методами типа GET и POST, которое размещается на IIS express. При проверки его работоспособности с использованием Insomnia проблем не возникает, однако при попытке совершить к нему POST запрос используя JS (Node js) с удаленного хоста происходит зависание. При этом, при GET запросах все работает нормально.
Отмечу, что, используя Insomnia, проверка также осуществлялась с удаленного хоста. В самом API производиться логирование начала и конца запросов, из чего видно, что запрос к API приходит. В чем может быть проблема?